# カメラアクセスと写真のアップロードが実機でできない

Tags: swift

カメラアクセスと写真のアップロードが実機でできません。
plistに

```
<dict>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>フォトライブラリの使用許可をお願いします</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string></string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>カメラの使用許可をお願いします</string>
<key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
<string></string>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>en</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>1</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
<string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
<string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
</dict>
```

と書き、
コントローラには

```
import UIKit

class SendController:UIViewController,
UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

//定数
let ButtonCamera = 0
let ButtomRead = 1
let ButtonWrite = 2

//変数
var imageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
var btnCamera:UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
var btnRead:UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)
var btnWrite:UIButton = UIButton(type: .custom)


//ロード完了時に呼ばれる
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// //カメラボタン生成
// self.view.addSubview(btnCamera)
// //読み込み
// self.view.addSubview(btnRead)
// // イメージビューの生成
// self.view.addSubview(imageView)

imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
view.addSubview(imageView)

btnCamera.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 100, height: 100)
btnCamera.setTitle("Camera", for: .normal)
btnCamera.tag = ButtonCamera
btnCamera.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
btnCamera.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
self.view.addSubview(btnCamera)

btnRead.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 100, height: 100)
btnRead.setTitle("Read", for: .normal)
btnRead.tag = ButtomRead
btnRead.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
btnRead.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
self.view.addSubview(btnRead)

btnWrite.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 300, width: 100, height: 100)
btnWrite.setTitle("Write", for: .normal)
btnWrite.tag = ButtonWrite
btnWrite.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.onClick(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
btnWrite.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
self.view.addSubview(btnWrite)
}

//ボタンクリック時に呼ばれる
func onClick(sender:UIButton){
if sender.tag == ButtonCamera {
openPicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)
}else if sender.tag == ButtomRead {
openPicker(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary)
}

}

//アラートの表示
func showAlert(title: String?, text: String?) {
let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: text, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//イメージピッカーのオープン
func openPicker(sourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceType){
if !UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(sourceType){
showAlert(title: nil, text: "利用できません")
return
}

//イメージピッカーの生成
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
picker.sourceType = sourceType
picker.delegate = self

//ビューコントローラーのビューを開く
present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// // イメージピッカーのイメージ取得時に呼ばれる
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]as! UIImage
imageView.image = image
//ビューコントローラーのビューを閉じる
picker.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true,completion:nil)
}

// //イメージピッカーのキャンセル取得時に呼ばれる
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
picker.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


}
```

と書きました。
Xcodeから自分のiPhoneでアプリを起動したのですが 
Camera access ボタンとPhoto upload ボタンは自分のiPhoneで表示されたのですが 
それらは押せるだけしか機能がありません。Camera access ボタンを押したら、iPhone（実機）のカメラが開いて写真が撮れて、撮った写真をアプリに表示させたいです。Photo upload ボタンを押したら、iPhone（実機）のカメラロールが開き元からある写真の中から一枚を選べ、選択した写真をアプリに表示させたいです。どう直せば良いでしょうか？

Comment: すみません、実機で、での意味です

Comment: 何か必要なコードが足りないということですか？

Comment: さて、本題の方でまだまだ不明なことが多いので他のコメントは削除させていただきました。あなたのコードでは「Camera」「Read」「Write」の3つのボタンが表示されますが、「Camera access ボタン」と「Photo upload ボタン」と言うのは最初の2つと言うことで良いのでしょうか。また「本当の機能ができません」とありますが、あなたのコードは`UIImagePickerController`を呼び出したらそれで終了しているので、何があなたの望む「本当の機能」なのかが全くわかりません。それぞれのボタンを押すとどのような動作が起こってほしいのか、今現在のコードではどのようになってしまうのか、自分以外の人にきちんとわかるように説明してみてください。

Comment: 追加しました。回答をお願いします。

Comment: あなたのコードをこちらのテスト機2機で動かしてみたのですが、「Camera」ボタン⇒「写真撮影の画面になり、シャッターボタンを押して撮影後に『Use Photo』ボタンを押すと元の画面に戻り撮影した画像が`UIImageView`に表示される」、「Read」ボタン⇒「デバイス内に保存された写真の選択画面が現れ、その中から１枚を選ぶと元の画面に戻り選択した画像が`UIImageView`に表示される」と言う動作をします。撮影画像の保存やuploadの機能はないものの、あなたが「させたい」こととして編集後のご質問内容に記述された通りの動作になっているように思われます。もっと他に手がかりになる情報(`SendController`以外のコード、特に`SendController`を表示させる部分、あるいはstoryboardの設定が絡んでいるかも知れません)がないと、今の情報だけではわからないですね。とにかく「ご質問に記載のコードを普通に表示させれば、記載通りの動作をする」と言うのを前提に、もう一度何か気になる部分がないかを調べてみてください。全く新しい新規のプロジェクトを作成し、同じ事象が再現できるようになるまでソースコードを少しずつ追加していく、と言うのも問題を切り分ける役に立つことがあります。

Comment: なるほど！確かにstoryboar‌​dとSendControllerの接続が悪そうです。ありがとうございます！